# Ultrasonic sensor with Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm student, and I'm not good at English..
but, I have a problem and I think you can solve this problem
I'm making a circuit with LED and speaker on through ultrasonic sensors. But what should I do to make the sound come out once within a certain distance, and to make the sound come out again when I come back from a certain distance?
please I need your help...

That is my circuit

```
 int distance = 0;

int i = 0;

long readUltrasonicDistance(int triggerPin, int echoPin)
{
  pinMode(triggerPin, OUTPUT); // clear thr trigger
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the trigger pin to HIGH status for 10 microseconds
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  // Reads thr echo Pin, and returns the sound wave
  return pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
    distance = 0.01723 * readUltrasonicDistance(5,4);
  if (distance > 40) {
    noTone(11);
  }
  delay(1000); // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)
}

void loop()
{ distance = 0.01723 * readUltrasonicDistance(5,4); 
  if (distance < 40) {
    tone(11,523,500); // play tone 60
    delay(1000); // wait for 1000 millisecond(s)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a variable for specifying if the distance is reached once. and reset the variable only id distance is far away. and use that variable to play sound once and update the variable.

```
bool came = false;

void setup(){
//remaining stuff here
}

void loop()
{ distance = 0.01723 * readUltrasonicDistance(5,4); 
  if (distance < 40 && !came) {
    //tone code here
    came = true;
  }
  if (distance >= 40) {
   come = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. but there is some error..... In function 'void loop()':
29:25: error: 'came' was not declared in this scope
34:4: error: 'came' was not declared in this scope
 exit status 1  ----------------------------- how to solve it?

Comment: you need to declare bool came = false outside the setup function as global variable.
I have also edited the answer.